# Ajax Server-Side synchronized HTTP request?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am building a website which has a cron job that generates a file to the hard drive regularly. However, the timing of this generation is not precise and I would like it to be loaded as soon as it is generated by the browsers of my visitors.

Is there a nice way to make my server notify my visitor's browser to reload the page?
Other way around is quite heavy :(

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you should read about **Comet**, Comet allows you the receive "Push" from server-side to your client-side.

Eg,. thats the way how facebook chat works..

Take a look,
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)